Keep intercept when using `feols()` from fixest
I am running a regression with fixed effects and would like to retain the intercept:
library(causaldata)
library(fixest)
data("auto")
summary(feols(mpg ~ weight + gear_ratio | rep78 + length, data = auto))

OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: mpg
Observations: 69
Fixed-effects: rep78: 5,  length: 43
Standard-errors: Clustered (rep78) 
           Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|) 
weight     0.000922   0.003025 0.304752  0.77575 
gear_ratio 1.469555   2.142034 0.686056  0.53038 
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 1.85278     Adj. R2: 0.655872
                Within R2: 0.011398

The intercept gets dropped. However, when running the same regression in Stata:
sysuse auto
reghdfe mpg weight gear_ratio, absorb(rep78 length)

(dropped 27 singleton observations)
(MWFE estimator converged in 5 iterations)

HDFE Linear regression                            Number of obs   =         42
Absorbing 2 HDFE groups                           F(   2,     20) =       0.12
                                                  Prob > F        =     0.8917
                                                  R-squared       =     0.8296
                                                  Adj R-squared   =     0.6507
                                                  Within R-sq.    =     0.0114
                                                  Root MSE        =     3.4414

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |    .000922    .004538     0.20   0.841     -.008544     .010388
  gear_ratio |   1.469555   3.102964     0.47   0.641    -5.003115    7.942225
       _cons |   14.08067   20.64539     0.68   0.503    -28.98485     57.1462
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Absorbed degrees of freedom:
-----------------------------------------------------+
 Absorbed FE | Categories  - Redundant  = Num. Coefs |
-------------+---------------------------------------|
       rep78 |         4           0           4     |
      length |        17           1          16     |
-----------------------------------------------------+


the intercept is kept.
